# Run-Time Check Failure #0 when using a library

Tags: c++, c, pdf, compiler-errors, static-libraries

I am trying to make a small program using the Haru PDF library (http://libharu.sourceforge.net/index.html). I am linking it statically with my project and have some basic source code to test if the library works successfully. The source code is as follows.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "hpdf.h"

void ErrorHandler(HPDF_STATUS errorNo, HPDF_STATUS errorDetail, void* userData)
{
    std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    HPDF_Doc pdf = HPDF_New(ErrorHandler, nullptr);
    if (!pdf)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    HPDF_Free(pdf);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile the program I get the following error:

```
Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.
```

Through some research I have discovered it may be due to different calling conventions. However, I am at a loss as to how to go about fixing this problem. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try some calling conversions:

```
void WINAPI ErrorHandler(...)

void __stdcall ErrorHandler(...)

extern "C" {
void ErrorHandler(...)
}
```

or other.